# append li to table td using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append ul ol to td, i tried for a few tags h3, it's working but I do the same for ul ol the data is mismatching within table format, as I am new to javascript any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance. Below is my code. Also, I'm unable to add the library version in the snippet. Please help

```js
var h2data = document.getElementsByClassName('carname');
    var title_array=[];
    for(var i=0; i< h2data.length; i++){
    title_array.push(h2data[i].innerText);
       
    }
     console.log(title_array);
     
    var pdata_detail = document.getElementsByClassName('car_details');
    var pdata_array=[];
    for(var i=0; i< pdata_detail.length; i++){
    pdata_array.push(pdata_detail[i].innerText);
       
    }
     console.log(pdata_array);  

    var dscdata = document.getElementsByClassName('features');
    var desc_array=[];
    for(var i=0; i< dscdata.length; i++){
    desc_array.push(dscdata[i].innerText);
       
    }
     console.log(desc_array); 

     
    var soldes = document.getElementsByClassName('feature_detail');
    var soldetail_array=[];
    for(var i=0; i< soldes.length; i++){
    soldetail_array.push(soldes[i].innerText);
       
    }
     console.log(soldetail_array);
```

```html
<h1>List of cars</h1>
        <h2 class="carname">BMW</h2>
        <h3 class="car_details">Manuf Details</h3>        
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Top 10 Most Popular Car Features </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Touchscreen infotainment system </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Music System.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Panoramic Sunroof.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Music System</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>LED DRLs.</p>
            </li>            
        </ul>
        <h3 class="features">good features:</h3>
        <p class="feature_detail">Fast USB Charging Outlets & Wireless Charger.</p>
        
        
        <h2 class="carname">Brimstone</h2>
        <h3 class="car_details">Manuf Details:</h3>        
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Front Bumper</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Fender</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h3> Areas:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Rear Bumper</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Grille</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
        
        <h2 class="carname">Smoke</h2>
        <h3 class="car_details">Manuf Details</h3>
        <p class="">dec 2021</p>
        <ol start="1">
            <li>
                <p>The darkest of smokes emitted from the exhaust </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>The spark at ignition can only combust a certain amount</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>conditions can be caused by a leaking fuel injector</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>only will this constrict the volume of air</p>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <p>Blueish hue can be found from cars</p>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <p>Head gasket failure types:</p>
        <ol start="1">
            <li>
                <p>Compression leaks to crankcase smoking </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Blown to outside oil leak</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Blown to outside coolant leak.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Compression leak to coolant overheating.</p>
            </li>            
        </ol>
        <h3 class="features">good Feature:</h3>
        <p class="feature_detail">Exhaust products that make it to the outside world can vary in colour,. </p>
        
        <button onclick="addTable()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see where there is `<table>` element.

Comment: Also where is `addTable()` defined.

Comment: @Twisty, i have called upon click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following jQuery example.

```js
$(function() {
  function getCarDetails() {
    var results = [];
    var car;
    $(".carname").each(function(i, el) {
      car = {
        carname: $(el).text(),
        pname: $(el).siblings(".car_details").eq(i).text(),
        desc: $(el).siblings(".features").eq(i).text(),
        soldetail: $(el).siblings(".feature_detail").eq(i).text(),
      }
      results.push(car);
    });
    return results;
  }

  $("button").click(function(event) {
    var myData = getCarDetails();
    console.log(myData);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>List of cars</h1>
<h2 class="carname">BMW</h2>
<h3 class="car_details">Manuf Details</h3>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Top 10 Most Popular Car Features </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Touchscreen infotainment system </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Music System.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Panoramic Sunroof.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Music System</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>LED DRLs.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3 class="features">good features:</h3>
<p class="feature_detail">Fast USB Charging Outlets & Wireless Charger.</p>


<h2 class="carname">Brimstone</h2>
<h3 class="car_details">Manuf Details:</h3>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Front Bumper</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Fender</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3> Areas:</h3>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Rear Bumper</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Grille</p>
  </li>
</ul>


<h2 class="carname">Smoke</h2>
<h3 class="car_details">Manuf Details</h3>
<p class="">dec 2021</p>
<ol start="1">
  <li>
    <p>The darkest of smokes emitted from the exhaust </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>The spark at ignition can only combust a certain amount</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>conditions can be caused by a leaking fuel injector</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>only will this constrict the volume of air</p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <p>Blueish hue can be found from cars</p>
  </li>
</ol>
<p>Head gasket failure types:</p>
<ol start="1">
  <li>
    <p>Compression leaks to crankcase smoking </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Blown to outside oil leak</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Blown to outside coolant leak.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Compression leak to coolant overheating.</p>
  </li>
</ol>
<h3 class="features">good Feature:</h3>
<p class="feature_detail">Exhaust products that make it to the outside world can vary in colour,. </p>

<button>Click me</button>
```

This results in giving you an Array of Objects:

```
[
  {
    "carname": "BMW",
    "pname": "Manuf Details",
    "desc": "good features:",
    "soldetail": "Fast USB Charging Outlets & Wireless Charger."
  },
  {
    "carname": "Brimstone",
    "pname": "Manuf Details:",
    "desc": "good Feature:",
    "soldetail": "Exhaust products that make it to the outside world can vary in colour,. "
  },
  {
    "carname": "Smoke",
    "pname": "Manuf Details",
    "desc": "",
    "soldetail": ""
  }
]
```

As you tagged this question with jQuery, I am using the jQuery Framework for ease of use. You can do similar with JavaScript itself.

The basics of this is ti iterate over each Elements with the Class of `carname` and use this as point of reference to the other elements. You can then use `.text()` to get the Text from the element.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- https://api.jquery.com/siblings/
- https://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: the result I want is in table format. I tried the above answer no luck.